# os.startfile() path in python with numbers

Tags: python, path

I am working on a little project in python for work.
It involves opening a file with the `os.startfile()`

And there in lies my problem :

the path to the file contains several numbers. And for some reason I don't understand this cause problems in locating the file.

Is there a work around for this?

Because I can't change the names of the directory or the file.

Comment: can you provide an example of a path that's not working?

Comment: G:\database\6541455.docx When i change the numbers into tekst it works

Comment: Ok I posted an answer. Let me know if it resolves the issue

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `\` character has a special meaning in python, e.g. `\n` is a newline etc.

You can either do:

```
os.startfile(r"G:\EEGdatabase\6541455.docx")
```

Or:

```
os.startfile("G:\\EEGdatabase\\6541455.docx")
```

To solve the problem.

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals for details.