# Can't access file on remote server with os.startfile

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to access a test text file on a server with the command os.startfile but I can't seem to make it work. I know it only fails because the text file is on the server and not on the computer but I have no idea how to access it.

Here's my code :

```
from os import startfile
path = "//10.2.30.61/c$/Qlikview_Tropal/Raport/test1.txt"
startfile("//10.00.00.00/c$/test/test1/test1.txt")
```

And I get this error : FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]. I am on windows by the way.

Update_1 : I tried the `enter os.startfile(os.path.normpath())` and i get this error : "filenotfounderror winerror 53 the network path was not found"

Thank you !!

Comment: are you able to access the file with this path in your OS, such as with Windows Explorer or a command line shell?

Comment: You can not have numbers here is a fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/43205543/14579156

Comment: Seems `startfile` does not like forward slashes, at least on my Windows machine. Try `os.startfile(os.path.normpath(path))`

Comment: Yes i can access it with the explorer, maybe it is because i am using a vpn? I dont see how it would affect it tho.

Comment: I tried the enter os.startfile(os.path.normpath()) and i get this error : "filenotfounderror winerror 53 the network path was not found" @JustinEzequiel

Comment: @ShadowGunn Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it ? Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```py
from os import start file


#put two \\ to get one \
path = "\\\\10.2.30.61\\c$\\Qlikview_Tropal\\Raport\\test1.txt"
startfile(r"\\10.00.00.00\c$\test\test1\test1.txt")
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43205543/14579156

Comment: the reason why you can not have //10.00.00.00/c$/test/test1/test1.txt is because you have to have \ instead